# In PHP, output as byte array and stream. Which one is better?

Tags: php, service, stream, arrays

i need to write a php web service to output file to a Windows client application. I have two choice Byte Array and Streaming. Which one is better and easy to implement in PHP?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: what do you mean by Byte Array and Streaming?

Comment: I can send out a file to the client as ByteArray or stream it out

Answer (score 0):

How about just....

```
$file = 'some_file.exe';

$_size = filesize($_file);
header('Content-Type: binary/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.$_size);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"; size=" . $_size);

@readfile($file);
```

Note: see the comment about [some issues with binary files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#76358), however.

Comment: You should use [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/readfile) instead of `echo`ing the read contents. I don't think this is really what the OP is asking for though.

Comment: @deceze: It's funny (and probably due to fatigue) I was thinking `file()` first (knew that wasn't right) then went to `file_get_contents()`. `readfile()` is, you're right, the better fit. However, I was more just showing that you'd do a combo between headers and outputting content to get the desired result.