# Output a PDF in PHP from a byte array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, curl

I am getting a byte array from a WCF service that generated the PDF and converted it to a byte array. I need to able to get the byte array and using either PHP or Javascript (or jQuery) take that byte array and convert it back to a downloadable PDF. I would prefer a solution in Javascript, but PHP would work fine too.

The code I'm using to get the PDF is:

```
<?php
    $userPDF = $_POST['username'];
    $passPDF = $_POST['password'];
    $idPDF = 'MO-N007175A';

    //PDF Function
    $data = array("id" => $idPDF, "username" => $userPDF, "password" => $passPDF);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                
    $ch = curl_init('http://********.com/******/v1/DealPdf');                                                                      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

The `var_dump($result);` is

`string(1053285) "[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,54,10,37,211,244,204,225,` ...

The array goes on for a while... so I only provided a small portion for example purposes.

Where do I start on getting a PDF out of this array?

**EDIT** 
To clarify - The WCF Service IS returning an actual PDF, just in a byte array. I need to save this byte array as a PDF on the clients machine. I have used fwrite and so forth, but I must be missing something because I dont see it working.

Also - If I do use fwrite, where does it output the file?
**EDIT**

Comment: JavaScript cannot do this. In PHP you'd send a MIME header for the PDF, then the byte stream.

Comment: byte is not enough to generate PDF... this byte of word, image, line anything...

Comment: So is this correct in sending a MIME header and writing out the byte stream? It's not working.. something I'm doing is wrong. What might it be? `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$fp = fopen( 'file.pdf', 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $result);
fclose( $fp );`

Comment: I am wondering why you asked this exact question on the 8th and accepted an answer. In any event, you say you are getting a byte array containing the contents of a pdf. why are you converting it? An unoptimized way to handle the byte array is to treat it as a string in php, and you can access the array items using the same array indices as the byte array. If the WCF service is indeed creating and returning data formatted as a PDF, then you just need to emit it to file (or to client w/ header).

Comment: I thought that answer previously (on the 8th) was correct, but it did not accomplish my eventual goal. I miss-understood what was happening. Yes, it contains contents of a PDF. Using "Convert" wasnt the correct term to use. Rather, I need to simple write this byte array out. I have yet to come across a solution that has worked... However, I will go back and change that question from a few days ago.

Comment: The result of your var_dump looks plain weird (`[37,80,68,70...`).. does that mean the wcf service actually sends a *string* representation of each bytes  in the source pdf file as base 10 values?

Comment: You're right - it is weird. I just assumed I was getting the right data back. It seems like it IS a string, and possible base 10. I will consult our .NET programmer.

Answer (score 17):

I had to do the same thing. For me, I was generating the PDF server-side, but wanted to send it down with a bunch of other data to the client in an AJAX response. Here's the JavaScript that I ended up with. The [Blob](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) and [saveAs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) methods are rather new technologies, so you might want to (as I did) get the polyfills for each of them, linked to above.

```
// Convert the Base64 string back to text.
var byteString = atob(data.reportBase64Bytes);

// Convert that text into a byte array.
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

// Blob for saving.
var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: "application/pdf" });

// Tell the browser to save as report.pdf.
saveAs(blob, "report.pdf");

// Alternatively, you could redirect to the blob to open it in the browser.
//document.location.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: It has been years since this has been posted, so things have changed a bit. I figured I'd just mention that atob is deprecated now. But importing and using Buffer works, and then you don't have to do the charCodeAt part either. The commented out document.location.href part did work for me, but I'm using a different method to download myself. (There are probably a lot of ways to do it.)

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought this would be a great use of the JavaScript library [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), but then I realized that you wanted to download the file. The **best place to do this would be in PHP** setting all of the appropriate headers along the way.

**However**, there may be something that will work for you, but **I have never tried it with PDFs**.  I have seen image saves done well with data url's in some browsers.  A great example of this is [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/).  The code would look something liket he following:

```
document.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64PDFdata;
```

Where `base64PDFdata` would be your byte array converted to base 64 string representation. **No guarantees on this working, but it may be worth a shot.**

Comment: That actually worked... kinda. I'm only testing in Chrome (Version 26.0.1410.64 m), and it failed if the file size was somewhere over 1,026KB. In my tests, 1,026KB and below worked but 1,754KB and above did not. I'm guessing this has something to do with max URL lengths in the browser. So this is only an applicable solution if you know your file sizes will be small, and perhaps not in all browsers.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense. Thanks Grinn =)

Comment: Did the file get downloaded as .pdf ? When I am trying to the same thing with byte array returned by web api on client, the file gets downloaded as "download" file with no extension.

Comment: Firefox supports data URLs of essentially unlimited length, but browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limited URLs to 65535 characters long which limits data URLs to 65529 characters (65529 characters being the length of the encoded data, not the source, if you use the plain data:, without specifying a MIME type).
source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems

Comment: @fromvega Yeah, in 2019 I wouldn't consider PHP the best place to do it anymore, but it depends on your requirements. I would use PDF.js or similiar and then fall back to PHP where needed.

Answer (score 1):

As mention in my comment to your question, it looks like you're getting a string representation of an array of decimal representations of bytes. e.g. `"[37,80,68,70]"`

You likely need to transform that.

Can be done like this:

```
// with:
$data = "[50,20,36,34,65]";

// remove brackets
$data = trim($data,'[]');

// split into array on ',' character
$data = explode(',',$data);

// transform each decimal value to a byte   representation. chr does just that
$data = array_map('chr',$data);

// turn the resulting array back into a string
$data = implode('',$data);
```

The comments about setting the headers to force download are also relevant so you should use that too.

Here's the final code:

```
<?php
// This is good to keep
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.pdf"');


$userPDF = $_POST['username'];
$passPDF = $_POST['password'];
$idPDF = 'MO-N007175A';

//PDF Function
$result = array("id" => $idPDF, "username" => $userPDF, "password" => $passPDF);                                                                    
$result_string = json_encode($result);                                                
$ch = curl_init('http://********.com/******/v1/DealPdf');                                                                      

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $result_string);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// remove brackets
$result = trim($result,'[]');

// split into array on ',' character
$result = explode(',',$result);

// transform each decimal value to a byte   representation. chr does just that
$result = array_map('chr',$result);

// turn the resulting array back into a string
$result = implode('',$result);

echo $result;
?>
```

Note that echo is used here, var_dump is not good as it adds extra formatting to the output.

Also, note, you're not doing any testing on the result of the curl, if it fails you should probably handle the output differently.

Comment: The PDF that downloads is blank and corrupt. When opened in textedit, it is blank as well.  When I get rid of the download PDF header, and simply echo the results its also blank.

Comment: Noted on the error handling. I will indeed do that once I get a few things working =)

Comment: Anything in the error log or do you have display_errors turned on?

Comment: I will turn on the display_errors tomorrow and see if there are any

Comment: Found the reason... echo $result; doesn't actually output the array bytes... you cant echo the contents of an array. Print_r doesnt work either, because it gives all the formatting - same with var_dump. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `echo $result;` isn't outputting an array, the previous `implode` statement turns the array into a string..

Comment: there must be some piece of information you haven't provided.. can you provide a full result from the wcf somewhere?

Comment: Yes. The full result is `string(1053285) "[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,54,10,37,211,244,204,225,` etc. It goes on for a while... that is exactly what the WCF is returning to me.

Comment: Can you you a sample of the _entire_ output somewhere (on dropbox or some server) so we can test it out to re-generate the output?

Comment: Yes I will make a dropbox and paste the output in a txt file if thats OK. email me mdance86 at hotmail dot com

Comment: @mdance. Just sent you an email

Answer (score 0):

Set MIME header with header() to match a PDF and then print out byte array.

Something like this:
[In PHP, output as byte array and stream. Which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182839/in-php-output-as-byte-array-and-stream-which-one-is-better)

Comment: This is what I am doing so far - obviously it doesnt work. What am I missing? Sorry Im new to PHP.`header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$fp = fopen( 'file.pdf', 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $result);
fclose( $fp );`

Answer (score 0):

Ahh now I see what you want to do!

Try this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

    $userPDF = $_POST['username'];
    $passPDF = $_POST['password'];
    $idPDF = 'MO-N007175A';

    //PDF Function
    $data = array("id" => $idPDF, "username" => $userPDF, "password" => $passPDF);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                
    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/test/file.pdf');                                                                      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: OK - so, its very close! It opens up a download dialog box for a PDF, however, the PDF is not readable.. it's corrupt in some way.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question. All this does is force the browser to download whatever the output is as a pdf.. your problem is that output isn't a pdf

Comment: How would I go about getting the output to be a pdf? I have tried fopen, fwrite etc... but it doesnt seem to work. When I echo the $result, the PDF that opens (when I open it with textedit) does contain the byte array... however Im assuming its just a string of numbers at that point.