# Base64 encode/decode and download content generated in URL

Tags: javascript, base64

I am generating a string through JavaScript and I need to download it to a text file with a predefined dynamic filename. This way there will be no room for error by employees.

This is obviously not possible in JavaScript due to security issues. However, from what I have read it should be possible with base64 encoding.

I managed to encode the string and open a url with the decoded data. The string has been decoded successfully in this URL. The format is as follows:

```
var data = 'data:text/plain;base64,'+L_EncodedData;
document.location = data;
```

I need to open a file dialog with the decoded data so the employees can download the content generated in this URL.

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for a solution that works entirely on the client?

Comment: ideally yes. I know that you cannot download the file automatically due to security issues. But there should be a way in which you redirect to a base64 url which in turns open a save dialog in the format xxxx.txt. It is then up to the user whether to download it or not.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do anything like that. Why not send the data to a server and expose it through an HTML link?

Comment: because I do not want to put more load on the server and also I don't need to store the text file physically on the server. All I need is for the end user to download a simple text file. In ExtJS there is a playing which does the same thing but exporting to Excel. All I need is something similar but which exports to a text file

Comment: Ok, so I stumbled upon some more info on this. If you are able to limit your user base to modern browsers that support the File API, you can use the blob URI scheme to download files locally. Check this link http://eligrey.com/blog/post/tag/file-api for some examples. Unfortunately this an HTML5 feature and support for even IE10 is unknown.

Comment: Yes I have read about that. However I ended up doing it server side for better control.

Answer (score 3):

If you're still looking for an answer to this, check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707604/output-a-pdf-in-php-from-a-byte-array/16350999#16350999). This is how I would adapt it for your needs.

```
// Convert the Base64 string back to text.
var txt = atob(data.reportBase64Bytes);

// Blob for saving.
var blob = new Blob([byteString], { type: "text/plain" });

// Tell the browser to save as report.txt.
saveAs(blob, "report.txt");
```

If you use this, make sure you grab the polyfills that I mention in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

This block is fixed.

```
window.OpenWindowForBase64 = function(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    var w = window.open("");
    w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    if (callback) {
        callback(url);
    }
}
```