# How to download attachment from gmail api using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm creating a web app to read my e-mails using gmail api. All methods is working (users.messages.list, users.messages.get, etc...) and displaying in console.log and in my page HTML. One thing I have noticed that I have to use **atob** to decode the **body.data** and insert in my HTML. Now I have to download or read the attachment for exemple **file.docx**, and I'm using this exemple [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) after the callback I noticed that I have to decode too, but if I do, there is no link to download or read, only some code from microsoft word. If I copy this code and create a doc and paste it, says the file is corrupted.

My code:

```
function getAttachments(messageID, parts, callback) {
    //console.log(parts);
    var attachId = parts.body.attachmentId;
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
        'id': attachId,
        'messageId': messageID,
        'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function (attachment) {
        callback(parts.filename, parts.mimeType, attachment);
    });
}

if (att.length > 0) {
    for (var i in att) {
        getAttachments(response.id, att[i], function (filename, mimeType, attachment) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(filename, mimeType, attachment);
            console.log(atob(attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')));
            inline.append('<a href="" style="display: block">' + filename + '</a>');
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707604/output-a-pdf-in-php-from-a-byte-array/16350999#16350999)

Comment: How about `window.location = 'data:'+mimeType+';base64,'+attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');`

Comment: It's worked, but when I click on my link the browser start a download named "download.doc" there is a way to download the doc with the real name? And I realized when I try to download a big file like a .rar (11MB) it doesn't work.

Comment: The code is: `var link = 'data:' + mimeType + ';base64,' + attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'); inline.append('<a href="' + link + '" style="display: block">' + filename + '</a>');`

Comment: when i am using gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get then it throughs gmail is undefined...and how to pass the authroziation..Plz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution.

**HTML**

```
<a id="download-attach" download="filename"/>
```

**JS**

```
function getAttachments(messageID, parts, callback) {
    var attachId = parts.body.attachmentId;
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
      'id': attachId,
      'messageId': messageID,
      'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function (attachment) {
      callback(parts.filename, parts.mimeType, attachment);
    });
  }

if (att.length > 0) {
    for (var i in att) {
       getAttachments(response.id, att[i], function (filename, mimeType, attachment) {

       let dataBase64Rep = attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')

       let urlBlob = b64toBlob(dataBase64Rep, mimeType, attachment.size)

       let dlnk = document.getElementById('download-attach')
       dlnk.href = urlBlob
       dlnk.download = filename
       dlnk.click()
       URL.revokeObjectURL(urlBlob)
   }
}

function b64toBlob (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || ''
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data)
  var byteArrays = []

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize)

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers)

    byteArrays.push(byteArray)
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType})
  let urlBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  return urlBlob
}
```