# nodejs gmail api - attachment download url

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail

so i got the attachment id from the api, and the payload is data in bytes

*from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments#resource*

> The body data of a MIME message part as a base64url encoded string.........

so i tried decoding it with https://github.com/brianloveswords/base64url
and few other base64 plugins - all returing another unreadable string format.

since i wasn't sure if it was an actual file or decoded url i tried exporting contents to a file with known extension without much success, so it should be a download link.

does anyone have any idea how to get a readable format of this string?

**payload string sample**

```
1op669AzYx7c9caYxOd0ZWzNE7IqPyUUnmRkib4HPAUbc3FzzEs7xWl6glqXXo2Y_hjSfT9CtS0THzTkf2rZ8UbKU6S
```

**base64 utf8 decoded sample**

```
↑8�k垬☼A��VN��\�>�/i��U�ՁR∟F����A�☺ň<�v¶��C� I-t��]⌂�R☺
```

string is much muh bigger, testing can be done here for full response https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get

**UPDATE**

Solved it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16350999/7579200

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use the [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) function.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't precise enough. i did use it, thats where i got the response from. the link i provided is for the specification what should a response be.

Comment: Did you try the API on Google website? (cam be accessed with my link)

Comment: yes i did, but i don't understand how is that relevant? it is the same response that i get from my node gmail configuration.